# How to mock/stub activate() method in AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, tdd

I'm currently working on a large AngularJS application, very much based on the excellent [AngularJS Styleguide by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1).

One of his recommendations is the use of an `activate()` method as a sort of bootstrapper for every controller. This makes your code structure clear and you immediately know where bootstrapping begins. Often times, I use it to load data (I prefer this over route-resolves).

The problem I'm facing is how should I unit-test the `methodUnderTest()`-method in the below code example without running the `activate()`-method.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp', [])
        .controller('ControllerUnderTest', ControllerUnderTest);

    ControllerUnderTest.$inject = [];

    /* @ngInject */
    function ControllerUnderTest() {
        var vm = this;

        // attach functions to vm
        vm.activate = activate;
        vm.methodUnderTest = methodUnderTest;

        // activate
        activate();

        function activate() {
            // controller start-up logic
        }

        function methodUnderTest() {
            // how to test this method, without running the activate() method
        }
})();
```

Below is the test-code I currently have, but as you would expect it will always run the `activate()` method (which is not what I want).

```
(function() {

    var scope, createController;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    describe('ControllerUnderTest', function(){
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            createController = function() {
                return $controller('ControllerUnderTest', { 'scope': scope });
            };
        }));

        it('should be defined', function() {
            var controller = createController();
            expect(controller).toBeDefined();
        });

        it('should have a methodUnderTest', function() {
            var controller = createController();
            expect(controller.methodUnderTest).toBeDefined();
        });

    });
})();
```

How do I test `ControllerUnderTest.methodUnderTest()` without running the `activate()` method?

Comment: You had to mock all calls inside the activate method, do not execute the initialization method is not a good test

Comment: Thanks fantarama, but what if there is a lot of stuff happening in the `activate()` method, with a lot of different dependencies (services), which are not usefull for the methodUnderTest?

Comment: Services useless for the test must be mocked with void implementations or with fixed return values

Comment: Thank you Fantarama. If you supply your comments in an answer i'd be happy to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a module unit-test you had to mock all dependencies that are out of test scope.

Someting like:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.service("myService", function () {
        this.myMethod = function () {
            return "myValue";
        };
    });
}));
```